# Maya Python: Script execution loop and error R6025

Tags: python, visual-c++, runtime-error, infinite-loop, maya

So, when running the following script, it does 2 thing i dont want, nor understand. 
first of all, it gets into an execution loop, where it is constantly executing over and over again after it ran through.

The second thing is, after the second or third execution, i get a maya crashing error.

Its a Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library Error, reading:

```
Runtime Error!
Programm: C\Maya.exe
R6025
-pure virtual function call
```

Here is the Script i am running. Its just for doing a playblast.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel
import os
import sys

# Set Episode Number
promptResult = cmds.promptDialog(message='Episode Number',button=["Set", "Cancel"], cancelButton='Cancel', dismissString='Cancel')
if promptResult == "Set":
    episodeNumber = cmds.promptDialog( query=True, text=True)
if promptResult == "Cancel":
    sys.exit()

str(episodeNumber)

# Set Shot Number
promptResult = cmds.promptDialog(message='Shot Number',button=["Set", "Cancel"], cancelButton='Cancel', dismissString='Cancel')
if promptResult == "Set":
    shotNumber = cmds.promptDialog( query=True, text=True)
if promptResult == "Cancel":
    sys.exit()

str(shotNumber)

# Set Version Number
promptResult = cmds.promptDialog(message='Version Number',button=["Set", "Cancel"], cancelButton='Cancel', dismissString='Cancel')
if promptResult == "Set":
    versionNumber = cmds.promptDialog( query=True, text=True)

str(episodeNumber)

# Start Frame
promptResult = cmds.promptDialog(message='Start Frame',button=["Set", "Cancel"], cancelButton='Cancel', dismissString='Cancel')
if promptResult == "Set":
    startFrame = cmds.promptDialog( query=True, text=True)
if promptResult == "Cancel":
    sys.exit()

# End Frame
promptResult = cmds.promptDialog(message='End Frame',button=["Set", "Cancel"], cancelButton='Cancel', dismissString='Cancel')
if promptResult == "Set":
    endFrame = cmds.promptDialog( query=True, text=True)
if promptResult == "Cancel":
    sys.exit()    


if len(shotNumber) == 0:
    print "You must Specify a Shot Number"
    sys.exit()
elif len(episodeNumber) == 0:
    print "You must Specify an Episode Number"
    sys.exit()
elif len(startFrame) == 0:
    print "You must Specify an Episode Number"
    sys.exit()
elif len(endFrame) == 0:
    print "You must Specify an Episode Number"
    sys.exit()


# Sound Path
soundName1 = "FOLGE_"
soundName2 = "_WAVs_sh"
soundName = soundName1 + "" .join(episodeNumber) + "" .join(soundName2) + "" .join(shotNumber)
str(soundName)

# Save Playblast Path
PBPath1 = "X:\FOLGE_"
PBPath2 = "\playblasts\sh"
PBPath3 = "_placeholder_v"
PBPath4 = ".mov"
PBPath = PBPath1  + "" .join(episodeNumber) + "" .join(PBPath2) + "" .join(shotNumber) + "" .join(PBPath3) + "" .join(versionNumber) + "" .join(PBPath4)
print PBPath
str(PBPath)
cmds.playblast(filename=PBPath, sound=soundName, startTime=startFrame, endTime=endFrame ,format="qt", compression="H.264", quality=50)

sys.exit()
```

I have no idea what is causing both these problems. does anyone know more about either of which?

Comment: May I ask you why are you using sys.exit() in your code?

Comment: as i am pretty new to all this, i read about it, and now use it to cancel the script if certain criteria is false. the entire script is quite unprofessional i guess, as, like i said, i am new to all this.